# JSON deserialization not working after changing response string

Tags: c#, json, windows-phone

I want to deserialize following string:

```
YAHOO.Finance.SymbolSuggest.ssCallback({"ResultSet":{"Query":"google","Result":[{"symbol":"GOOG","name": "Google Inc.","exch": "NMS","type": "S","exchDisp":"NASDAQ","typeDisp":"Equity"},{"symbol":"GGQ1.DE","name": "GOOGLE-A","exch": "GER","type": "S","exchDisp":"XETRA","typeDisp":"Equity"}]}})
```

Which I download with a WebClient. But before I can deserialize, I need to remove "YAHOO.Finance.SymbolSuggest.ssCallback(" and the ")" at the end:

```
// get response
WebResponse response = request.EndGetResponse(result);
Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream();

// convert to string
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
string output = reader.ReadToEnd();
// cut string
output = output.Substring(39, output.Length - 40);
// convert back to stream
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(output));
```

So, the response I get is a stream. I convert that stream to a string, change the string and then convert the string back to a stream. Next, I try to deserialize:

```
// parse json
System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.DataContractJsonSerializer rootSer = new System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(RootObject));

// get root object
RootObject root = (RootObject)rootSer.ReadObject(ms);

// add to listbox
foreach (Result res in root.ResultSet.Result)
{
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => ResultList.Add(res));
}
```

The problem is I get a nullpointexeption in the foreach...
My classes are like so:

```
public class Result
{
    public string symbol { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string exch { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string exchDisp { get; set; }
    public string typeDisp { get; set; }
}

public class ResultSet
{
    public string Query { get; set; }
    public List<Result> Result { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public ResultSet ResultSet { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Regex to extract the json from jsonp

```
output = Regex.Match(output, @".+?\((.+?)\)").Groups[1].Value
```